# masonry layout on vertical not horizontal

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have found some very simple masonry layout now the problem is its displaying it on horizontal i want it to display on vertical. tried to change the masonry height but still display horizontally not so sure how

> display: flex

behaves with the other flex properties.

This is the [layout](http://prntscr.com/7up1wg) I would like to achieve

Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/michaelpon12/k0hbxofr/)

HTML:

```
<div id="masonry">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/1.jpg">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/2.jpg">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/3.jpg">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/4.jpg">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/6.jpg">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/8.jpg">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/9.jpg">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/7.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body { 
  margin: 0; background: #131212;  
  width: 100vw
} 
div#masonry { 
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vw;
  font-size: 0;  
}
div#masonry img {  
  width: 50%;
  transition: .8s opacity;
} 

div#masonry:hover img { opacity: 0.3; }
div#masonry:hover img:hover { opacity: 1; }
```

Comment: Can you show us the example output you like to have?

Comment: added on the question

Answer (score 0):

[->some guide<-](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
`flex-direction: row | row-reverse | column | column-reverse`;
in the: 
div#masonry img - you can play with width and/or **height** also, hope that helps :)

Comment: didn't get the css you put? whats the | stands for?

Comment: Michael Pon - just add height param to div#masonry

Comment: this is the one i didnt get flex-direction: row | row-reverse | column | column-reverse; whats with the | thing

Comment: this are possible parameters for 'flex-direction' separated by | sign (as additional info) in this case | = or